# How to remove an apt repository that I added myself?

Tags: apt, updates

I was following an old tutorial and did an apt-get installed a repository (I think that's what it was) I am no ubuntu guru.  Turns out that repo no longer exists, and when I now do an apt-get update I get this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I tried the usual

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

but no luck.  Where is the list that stores all the repos that i added myself?  How do I get rid of this?

Comment: That PPA doesn't support 15.10 (or anything newer than 13.10, for that matter). Remove it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The command to remove an apt repository is `apt-add-repository` with the `-r` option which will remove instead of add the repository. So in your case, the full command would be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:colingille/freshlight
```

The other option is to look in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and remove it from there.

Comment: _"The other option is to look in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and remove it from there."_ How exactly?

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ , this one worked for me, Pedro A, open a terminal, then * $ cd /etc/apt/sources.list * then * $ ls * then it will show list of folders, them remove the one you want * $ sudo rm repository.file *